# HTML file change to REACT

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm wondering if it's possible to change this HTML code to make it fit into React.For  example is if I try to put this HTML code into the REACT app. I also included the code for Node.js and MongoDB. Does it require a lot of change for the HTML code to make it fit in React? Is it necessary to include script and import DOM in the method to include it in REACT App?

This is home.ejs code use for upload and download files.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h2>Upload Files</h2>
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="pic"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form><br><br><br><br>
    <h2>Download Files</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        image
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        download
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% for(var i=0; i < data.length > 0; i++) {%>
                 <tr>
                     <td><img src="<%= data[i].picspath %>" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></td>
                     <td>
                         <form action="/download/<%= data[i]._id %>" method="GET">
                          <input type="submit" value="Download">
                        </form>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you can consider to use this site https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure just follow the following steps

1. Replace the opening and closing < html > tags with a < div > tag.
2. Replace the opening and closing < head > tags with a <React.Fragment>
   tag.
3. Replace the opening and closing < body > tags with a < div > tag.
4. Replace the <% and %> tags with curly braces { and } to indicate
   that the code between them is JavaScript.
5. Replace the <%= and %>tags with curly braces { and } to indicate that the code between them is an expression that should be rendered as a string.

```
<div>
<React.Fragment>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</React.Fragment>
<div>
  <h2>Upload Files</h2>
  <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pic" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <h2>Download Files</h2>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>download</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
         <tr>
          <td>
            <img src={item.picspath} style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <form action={`/download/${item._id}`} method="GET">
              <input type="submit" value="Download" />
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>)
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..It really help me to understand how it work.